# Use data file in PGF ternary plot

Tags: pgfplots, ternary-diagram

I want to plot a ternary diagram and I have a data set of 4 different values. 3 vol.% for making the point on the diagram and one which is the specific refractive indices at these concentrations. The refractive index should be a node at the point on the diagram (see picture).

I managed to write the code but it works only when I put the whole data set into the code.

```
\documentclass[border=15mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx, chemformula}
%%
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%%
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
    colorbar, 
    colormap/jet,
    xlabel = vol.\%(\ch{H2O}),
    ylabel = vol.\%(\ch{C2H5OH}),
    zlabel = vol.\%(\ch{CHCl3}),
    grid = both,
    label style = {sloped},
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={
        title={$n_D/\text{a.u}$},    
        samples=75,                  
        width=15,                   
        height=180,                 
        point meta min=1.330, 
        point meta max=1.440, 
        scaled y ticks = false,
        ytick = {1.330, 1.340, ..., 1.440},
        yticklabel={
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{\tick}
            \num[
                round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                round-mode = places,
                round-precision = 3,
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        yticklabel style={
            text width=3em,       
            align=right,        
        }
    }
  ]
   \addplot3+[only marks, 
   point meta=\thisrow{refindex},
   nodes near coords*={\tiny{\pgfmathprintnumber\refindex}},
  visualization depends on={\thisrow{refindex} \as \refindex} 
  ] 
  table[x = volPercentC, y = volPercentA, z = volPercentB] {
        volPercentA         volPercentB         volPercentC         refindex
        0.7                 0.0142857142857143  0.285714285714286   1.3498
        0.615384615384615   0.0256410256410256  0.358974358974359   1.3542
        0.583850931677019   0.0372670807453416  0.37888198757764    1.3564
        0.529411764705882   0.0588235294117647  0.411764705882353   1.3589
        0.421052631578947   0.105263157894737   0.473684210526316   1.364
        0.3                 0.2                 0.5                 1.3732
        0.2                 0.3                 0.5                 1.3828
        0.111111111111111   0.444444444444444   0.444444444444444   1.3946
        0.0625              0.5625              0.375               1.405
        0.0422535211267606  0.661971830985915   0.295774647887324   1.4129
        0.0285714285714286  0.685714285714286   0.285714285714286   1.4151
        0.0161290322580645  0.790322580645161   0.193548387096774   1.4257
  };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For such a small data set it might be sufficient but for larger ones not. I exclude the data in *data.txt* and changed the code to:

```
\documentclass[border=15mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx, chemformula}
%%
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%%
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
    colorbar, 
    colormap/jet,
    xlabel = vol.\%(\ch{H2O}),
    ylabel = vol.\%(\ch{C2H5OH}),
    zlabel = vol.\%(\ch{CHCl3}),
    grid = both,
    label style = {sloped},
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={
        title={$n_D/\text{a.u}$},    
        samples=75,                  
        width=15,                   
        height=180,                 
        point meta min=1.330, 
        point meta max=1.440, 
        scaled y ticks = false,
        ytick = {1.330, 1.340, ..., 1.440},
        yticklabel={
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{\tick}
            \num[
                round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                round-mode = places,
                round-precision = 3,
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        yticklabel style={
            text width=3em,       
            align=right,        
        }
    }
  ]
   \addplot3+[only marks, 
   point meta=\thisrow{refindex},
   nodes near coords*={\tiny{\pgfmathprintnumber\refindex}},
  visualization depends on={\thisrow{refindex} \as \refindex} 
  ] 
  table[x = volPercentC, y = volPercentA, z = volPercentB] {
        data.txt
  };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Usually, it works that way for normal scatter plots. But unfortunately, in this case, my log is blood red and no data is plotted.

[image: output]

Thanks for helping me out.

Greetings FH

Comment: Try `table[x = volPercentC, y = volPercentA, z = volPercentB] {data.txt};`, i.e. with no newlines around the filename.

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.